# Scattering influenced by truncated repulsive Coulombic potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, scattering

Consider the truncated repulsive Coulomb potential which has the form
$$
V=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{k}{r}-\frac{k}{a} & r>a \\
0 & r<a
\end{array}\right.
$$

Obtain closed-form expressions for the scattering angle and the differential scattering cross-section. These are most conveniently expressed in terms of a parameter measuring the distance of the closest approach in units of a. What is the total cross-section?

Could anyone please give some ideas to do it?